# Finite dimensional sets in C[0,1]

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

If we look at the space $C[0,1]$ of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ we can define  $\mathcal{C}:=\{\pi_{t_1,\ldots, t_d}^{-1}(B) : {t_1,\ldots, t_d} \in [0,1]$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)\}$, where $\pi_{t_1,\ldots, t_d}:C[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^d$.

On the other hand we can tread $C[0,1]$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$. On this space we can also define the finite-dimensional sets as $\mathcal{H}:=\{\tilde{\pi}_{t_1,\ldots, t_d}^{-1}(B) : {t_1,\ldots, t_d} \in [0,1]$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)\}$, where $\tilde{\pi}_{t_1,\ldots, t_d}:\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}\to \mathbb{R}^d$. We can then define the "trace" collection as $\mathcal{H}_C=\{H\cap C[0,1]:H\in\mathcal{H}\}$.

Are the collections $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{H}_{C}$ the same, i.e. do we have $\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{H}_{C}$? I know that they both generate the same $\sigma$-algebra, but I am not sure if this equality holds.

Comment: what is $\pi_{t_1,\dots,t_d}$, what is $\tilde\pi_{t_1,\dots,t_d}$, what is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, does $d$ vary or is it fixed in the definition of $\mathcal{C}$ and  $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: If I’m understanding the question right, in that $\pi_{t_1,\ldots,t_d}(f) := (f(t_1),\ldots,f(t_d))$ and similarly for $\tilde{\pi}$, then this is completely elementary: $\pi_{t_1,\ldots,t_d}^{-1}(B) = \tilde{\pi}_{t_1,\ldots,t_d}^{-1}(B) \cap C[0,1]$ for any $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$, without needing anything about continuity or the specifics of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.  All that’s relevant is that $C[0,1]$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$, and $\pi_{t_1,\ldots,t_d}$ is the restriction of $\tilde{\pi}_{t_1,\ldots,t_d}$ to this subset.

Comment: Sorry for not making clear what $\pi$ should be. I meant it exactly the way as you understood it. Thank you, I think I got confused by my own notations :D

Comment: The sets in $\mathcal H$ are by no means *finite-dimensional* (whatever this means for sets which aren't vector spaces). They are co-finite-dimensional.

Comment: They are called in most of the literature (see e.g. Billingsley) finite-dimensional sets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this property is very standard (It must have a name, I just don't remember).

More generally:

> Let $\mathcal C\subset 2^{X}$ be arbitrary family of subsets and $A\subset X$ be arbitrary subset. Denote $\mathcal C \cap_* A = \{B\cap A\mid B\in \mathcal C\}$. Then
>   $$
> \sigma^{\vphantom{l}}_A(\mathcal C_A) = \sigma(\mathcal C)\cap_* A.\tag{1}
> $$

($\sigma^{\vphantom{l}}_A$ means that we take a sigma-algebra as a family of subsets of $A$).

*Proof*: since $\sigma(\mathcal C)\cap_* A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $A$, we have the inclusion $\subset$ in $(1)$. Vice versa, define 
$$
\mathcal S = \{B\in \sigma(\mathcal C)\mid B\cap A \in \sigma^{\vphantom{l}}_A(\mathcal C_A)\}.
$$
It is easy to see that this is a $\sigma$-algebra and that $\mathcal C\subset \mathcal S$. Hence we have $\supset$ in $(1)$, qed